# R: How to match regex but not substring

Tags: regex, r, substring

I have regex string data but would like to exclude a substring

```
dat <- c('long_regex_other_stuff','long_regex_other_random.something')
(dat[grep('long_regex',dat)])
(dat[grep('long_regex.*(?!.*something$)',dat)])
```

The first grep output is expected

```
"long_regex_other_stuff"            "long_regex_other_random.something"
```

How to get the second grep to work?  The desired output is

```
"long_regex_other_stuff"
```

Ref: [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the preceding `.*` before the string `something` in the regex and add it after the negative lookahead,

```
> dat <- c('long_regex','long_regex.something')
> (dat[grep('long_regex(?!.*something).*',dat, perl=T)])
[1] "long_regex"
> (dat[grep('long_regex(?!.*\\bsomething\\b).*',dat, perl=T)])
[1] "long_regex"
```

`long_regex(?!.*something)` negative lookahead present in this regex asserts that there isn't a string `something` present after to the substring `long_regex`.

```
> dat <- c('long_regex_other_stuff','long_regex_other_random.something')
> (dat[grep('long_regex(?!.*\\bsomething\\b).*',dat, perl=T)])
[1] "long_regex_other_stuff"
```

Comment: Let me check this answer on the "actual" data...  This doesn't quite work, I'll change the example...

Comment: could you explain the reason? So that, we could provide an exact answer.

Comment: There's random characters between the long_regex and the ".something", that were not in the original example

Comment: I get the error "reason 'Invalid regexp'" when I apply it to the data.  Give me a few minutes to either update the example (again) or to correct the application...

Comment: i don't know how it gives invalid regex. Are you copied the exact regex i provided? Did you enable `perl=TRUE` parameter?

Comment: Yes, it works, I did leave off the perl=TRUE parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64251/discussion-between-user3969377-and-avinash-raj).